# Evaluating $\prod_p(1\pm\frac{4}{p^2})$ in Closed Form

Tags: closed-form, riemann-zeta, infinite-product, zeta-functions, euler-product

> Do either of the two infinite products $~\displaystyle\prod_{p~\in~\mathbb P}\bigg(1+\frac{2^2}{p^2}\bigg)~$ and $~\displaystyle\prod_{p~\in~\mathbb P}^{p~>~2}\bigg(1-\frac{2^2}{p^2}\bigg)~$ possess a closed 
>  form expression, where $\mathbb P$ represents the set of all primes ?

If not, do they at least possess a number-theoretical interpretation, like the [*Feller-Tornier constant*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Feller-TornierConstant.html), for instance, whose decimal expansion can be found on [*OEIS*](http://oeis.org/A065474) ?

---

The **motivation** behind this question can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259044).

---

The multiplicative inverse of $~\displaystyle\prod_{p~\in~\mathbb P}^{p~>~2}\bigg(1\pm\frac4{p^2}\bigg)~$ can be written as $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\mp~4)^{\Omega(2n+1)}}{(2n+1)^2}~,~$ where $\Omega(k)$ [represents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor#Omega_functions) the total number of prime factors of *k*, counted with multiplicity.

Comment: Let $\frac{1}{p^2}=x$. We my notice that
$$ 1+4x^2 = (1+x^2)^4 (1-x^4)^6 (1+x^6)^{20} (1-x^8)^{60} (1+x^{10})^{204}\cdots $$
where the exponents are the elements of the sequence [A027377][1] (number of irreducible polynomials with degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_4$). So by setting $x=\frac{1}{p}$ and multiplying over $p\in\mathscr{P}$ we have:

$$ \prod_{p\in\mathscr{P}}\left(1+\frac{4}{p^2}\right)=\left(\frac{\zeta(2)}{\zeta(4)}\right)^4 \zeta(4)^{-6}\left(\frac{\zeta(6)}{\zeta(12)}\right)^{20}\zeta(8)^{-60}\left(\frac{\zeta(10)}{\zeta(20)}\right)^{204}\cdots $$
[1]: https://oeis.org/A027377

Comment: I am not sure about closed form, but asymptotic definitely https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Could we at least ascribe a number-theoretical meaning to it, similar to that of the [Feller-Tornier constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Feller-TornierConstant.html), for instance ?

Comment: In general, $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\Omega(2n+1)}}{(2n+1)^k} ~=~ \Big(1+2^{-k}\Big)~\frac{\zeta(2k)}{\zeta(k)}.~$

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070645) question.